# Usar chave composta como PK ou não?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, modelagem, tabela-banco-de-dados

Tenho duas tabelas:

1- Serviço Contratado

2- Pagamento Serviço Contratado

1 serviço pode ter N pagamentos. Modelei a classe de Pagamento Serviço Contratado da seguinte maneira:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.pagamento_servico_contratado
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('pagamento_servico_contratado_id_seq'::regclass),
  id_servico_contratado integer NOT NULL,
  codigo_forma_pagamento character varying NOT NULL,  
  data date,
  valor numeric,
  observacao character varying
)
```

Estou usando para a chave primária o id sequencial. Em relação a integridade isso está correto ou deveria usar uma chave composta como PK sendo o id do pagamento e o id do serviço contratado?

Comment: Me parece correto, mas sem conhecer os requisitos não temos como saber. O certo ou errado não depende do banco de dados e sim do requisito.

Comment: Se uma combinação dos campos de sua tabela devem identificar univocamente cada linha de sua tabela então você deve colocar esta restrição de integridade na definição da tabela. Da maneira como você definiu nada impede que sejam inseridos múltiplos pagamentos , cada um com um id diferente pois será autoincrementado, mas que no mundo real se refiram a um mesmo pagamento. No PostgreSQL costuma-se utilizar o tipo `SERIAL` (ou `BIGSERIAL`) para este tipo de campo.

Answer (score 1):

Não acho que seja necessário a criação de uma chave primária composta na sua tabela de pagamentos.

Se um `Serviço Contratado` pode possuir múltiplos `Pagamentos`, a [cardinalidade](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinalidade_(modelagem_de_dados)) entre essas entidades seria de *um-para-vários* ou **1:N**.

Uma chave estrangeira só é capaz de referenciar chaves primárias, logo sua tabela de `Serviços Contratados` vai precisar de uma constraint de chave primária para que a tabela de `Pagamentos` seja capaz de referência-la.

Como [boa prática](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840162/should-each-and-every-table-have-a-primary-key), ambas as tabelas necessitam de uma chave primária, o que poderia garantir que não haveriam registros idênticos/duplicados em uma mesma tabela.

Sugiro uma modelagem mais ou menos assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O script SQL equivalente a essa modelagem seria algo como:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE public.pagamento_servico_contratado_id_seq;
CREATE SEQUENCE public.servico_contratado_id_seq;

CREATE TABLE public.servico_contratado
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('servico_contratado_id_seq'::regclass),
  data date,
  descricao character varying,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE public.pagamento_servico_contratado
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('pagamento_servico_contratado_id_seq'::regclass),
  id_servico_contratado integer NOT NULL,
  codigo_forma_pagamento character varying NOT NULL,  
  data date,
  valor numeric,
  observacao character varying,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (id_servico_contratado) REFERENCES public.servico_contratado (id)
);
```